# CloudKit receives and stores time correctly, returns UTC Time when queried

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I send a local date to my iCloud container, but when I query it, it returns a UTC date, does anyone know how to change this?

The date also seems to be inconsistent on the dashboard. As you can see, in the data list, the time is local. When I click on it and scroll to the time property, it's UTC.

[image: cloudkit dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`Date` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date):

> A specific point in time, independent of any calendar or time zone.

So when you are querying the Date from iCloud I am pretty sure you are getting a correct one since it is free of any time zone, so it's dependant on the formatter's locale/time zone when it comes to displaying it.

The date you seen on the record list is date formatter for the locale and timezone of your system. The date you see when you open record details is the same point in time but displayed as UTC date.

e.g. I live in Poland and my timezone is UTC+2 so for me the same Date (point in time) is displayed in the dashboard like this:

[image: records list in dashboard]
[image: the same record details]

Comment: I found this to be correct, when I po the record's time in the debug log it's UTC (probably because when I "po" it, it's still a string), but when I actually convert it to a "Date" type, it shows the local date. Thank you.